# XCUITest Doing action after assert or test failure

Tags: swift, assert, xcuitest

can i do an action in XCUITest after test failure, after assert or even if element not found or not hittable

app will stay like this for hours if fails or entered an assertion . 
like this [assert or fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJuqA.png)

can i let the test call a method if fails?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute a single test, it will stop in case of failure.
However, if you execute multiple tests together, it will not stop but instead log the failure, so that the other tests are still executed (see the Report navigator in the leftmost pane of Xcode).
And you can of course execute any method before you call a method that declares a test as failed. just call it before, say, `XCTFail("error message")`.

EDIT:
In function `setup()`, you should also set `continueAfterFailure = true`

Comment: i am using one TestCase class with multiple tests inside, tests stop if fails and i notice after a long time because i am busy working on other project.
my issue is the tests will stop if fails like this image:https://imgur.com/QiAEpp7 or like the image on the top,However i would like to know if there's a way to handle fails ,asserts or any issue like element not found in a custom methods ( i will let it send notification to my mobile) or at least can we let the test continue after failure to test the rest of the tests method?

Comment: or doing something like this in tearDown method 'if (testRun?.failureCount)! > 0 print("failed") } else { print("success")  }'

Comment: According to your screenshot, the execution stops because of a crash(i.e `fatal error`) in the app and not because of a failure. That's why the other tests are not executed or the test run doesn't stop.

Comment: Ah sorry ,i mean this [https://imgur.com/I4I7BEZ] and i get 'Assertion Failure: TickerChartUITests.swift:96: No matches found for Find: Descendants matching type TextField from input ' , and the test continue until fail and stop in "if(usernameField.value as...." line, unless i but return after XCTFail to exit the method

Comment: It looks you created a breakpoint where a test fails. You have to remove it.

Comment: Look here, my textField is not exist and i call a long press on it and i got this [https://imgur.com/ZVk9oTB] and [https://imgur.com/uL4rCbr]
i really appreciate your help and your time

Comment: Can you show me all the breakpoints in your project ? (The second tab from the right in the left pane)